# Working with several types of filters together

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have several different filter types.The type of filters is checkbox and rang-price and select-option.Each of these filters works individually.But I want group filters to work.please help my.

```js
let FlyList = [{
 "id": "1",
 "flight_number": "961",
 "type_ticket": "systemi",
 "airline": "ata",
 "fly_time": "04:00",
 "class_type": "economy",
 "price": "10000",
 "capacity": "2",
}, {
 "id": "2",
 "flight_number": "960",
 "type_ticket": "chartery",
 "airline": "Air-Tour",
 "fly_time": "08:00",
 "class_type": "Business",
 "price": "20000",
 "capacity": "3",
}, {
 "id": "3",
 "flight_number": "950",
 "type_ticket": "systemi",
 "airline": "taban",
 "fly_time": "11:00",
 "class_type": "Business",
 "price": "30000",
 "capacity": "5",
},
];

let filters = new Array();

function rangeSlider() {
 $(".range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
  hide_min_max: true,
  keyboard: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 150,
  from: 0,
  to: 140,
  type: 'double',
  step: 1,
  prefix: "$",
  grid: true,
  onFinish: function(data) {
   var _price = filters.findIndex(item => item.field === 'price');
   if (_price != -1) filters[_price]['value'] = [data.from, data.to];
   else addOrRemoveFilter('price', [data.from, data.to], true);
   customFilter();
   // console.log(addOrRemoveFilter('price', [data.from, data.to], true));
   
  }  
 });
}
function customFilter() {
 let filtered_list = [];
 FlyList.filter(item => {
  filters.forEach(function(el, i) {
   let _field = el['field'];
   let _value = el['value'];
   // console.log(_value);
   
   

   if (typeof(_value) === 'object' && _value.length) {
   
    if(parseInt(item[_field]) >= (parseInt(_value[0] * 1000)) && parseInt(item[_field]) <= (parseInt(_value[1]*1000))){
     filtered_list.push(item);
    }
    else{
     FlyList = [];
    }

   } else {
    let isMulti = _value.split(',');
 
    //RANGE PRICE SLIDER  
    if (isMulti.length > 1) {
     let time = miliseconds(item[_field].split(':')[0], item[_field].split(':')[1])
     let num1 = miliseconds(isMulti[0].split(':')[0], isMulti[0].split(':')[1]);
     let num2 = miliseconds(isMulti[1].split(':')[0], isMulti[1].split(':')[1]);
     if (time >= num1 && time <= num2) filtered_list.push(item);
    } else {
     //end RANGE PRICE SLIDER  
     item[_field] == _value ? filtered_list.push(item) : false;
    }
   }
  })
 });

 function miliseconds(hrs,min) {
  return((hrs*60*60+min*60)*1000);
 }

 $('#flights').updateDom(filtered_list.length ? filtered_list : FlyList, {
  animate: true,
 }); 
}




let filterCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.filtersAll');
filterCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 let filterTypeElement = findFilterTypeElement(e.target);
 if (filterTypeElement) {
  
  let field = filterTypeElement.getAttribute('data-field');
  let val = e.target.value;

  addOrRemoveFilter(field,val,e.target.checked);
  
  customFilter();
 }
 
}));


document.getElementById('optionAll').addEventListener('change' ,(e)=>{
 e.preventDefault();
 let filterTypeElement = findFilterTypeElement(e.target);
 if (filterTypeElement) {
  
  let field = filterTypeElement.getAttribute('data-field');
  let val = e.target.value;

  addOrRemoveFilter(field,val,true);

  for(var index = 0 ; index < e.target.options.length ; index++)
  {
   addOrRemoveFilter(field,e.target.options[index].value,false);
  }

  addOrRemoveFilter(field,val,true);
  
  customFilter();
 }
})


function addOrRemoveFilter(f,v,add) {
 if(add) {
  filters.push({field : f.toLowerCase() , value : v});
 } else {
  for(let i = 0;i < filters.length ; i++) {
   if(filters[i].field === f.toLowerCase() && filters[i].value === v) {
    filters.splice(i,1);
   }
  }
 }
 // console.log(filters);
}


function getParents(el, parentSelector /* optional */) {

 // If no parentSelector defined will bubble up all the way to *document*
 if (parentSelector === undefined) {
  parentSelector = document;
 }

 var parents = [];
 var p = el.parentNode;

 while (p && (p !== parentSelector || p.parentNode)) {
  var o = p;
  parents.push(o);
  p = o.parentNode;
 }
 parents.push(parentSelector); // Push that parentSelector you wanted to stop at

 return parents;
}

function findFilterTypeElement(el) {
 var result = null;
 var parents = getParents(el);

 parents.forEach((item) => {
  if (hasClass(item, 'filter_type') && result == null) {
   result = item;
  }
 });
 return result;
}

function hasClass(element, className) {
 return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') > -1;
}
```

Comment: Please remove anything that isn't directly related to the problem (like the slider stuff, or `getParents()`) and try to reduce the amount of code (fewer properties, remove unnecessary empty lines, ...) to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is have a single function that you call when any of the filters updates. I would structure it something like this (assuming there's a way for a filter to be inactive):

```
let filter1 = {
    isActive: () => {},
    passesFilter: item => {}
}

let filter2 = {
    isActive: () => {},
    passesFilter: item => {}
}

let filter3 = {
    isActive: () => {},
    passesFilter: item => {}
}

let filters = [filter1, filter2, filter3]

function passFilters(item) {
    return filters.every(filter => {
        if (!filter.isActive()) return true;
        return filter.passesFilter(item);
    })
}

function onFilterUpdate() {
    let itemsThatPass = items.filter(item => passFilters(item));
    // do something with itemsThatPass here
}
```